# using solve_ivp multiple times on incrementing time windows

Tags: scipy, physics, ode, differential-equations, motion

**TLDR**: I'm solving an ODE that represents the torques applied on a rotating wing that is connected to a motor using `scipy.solve_ivp`. It seems that the solution doesn't behave as needed, and I can't seem to understand why

---

Im working on a solution for the equation `phi'' = a*torque_{motor}-b*(phi')^2`, where `a` and `b` are constants and `torque_{motor}` changes every iteration. More specifically, I wish to solve this ODE in a loop, every time for a differnet time window `[t,t+dt],[t+dt,t_2*dt],...` where in every such window `torque_motor` is assigned with a new value (`float`) - this is like saying that I use different force from the motor every time-step.

A subset of my code is provided as minimal running example:

```
class Solver():
    def __init__(self):
        self.torque = 0

    def set_torque(self, new):
        self.torque = new

    def phi_derivatives(self, t, y):
        """
        A function that defines the ODE that is to be solved: I * phi_ddot = tau_z - tau_drag.
        We think of y as a vector y = [phi,phi_dot]. the ode solves dy/dt = f(y,t)
        """
        # for exact values use
        a = 1090179.6616082331
        b = 271.9406850484702

        phi, phi_dot = y[0], y[1]
        dy_dt = [phi_dot, a * self.torque - b * (phi_dot ** 2)]
        return dy_dt

#
phi_arr = []
phi_dot_arr = []
phi_ddot_arr = []
phi_0 = 0
phi_dot_0 = 0.01
start_t = 0
end_t = 0.05
delta_t = 0.001
s = Solver()
sin = np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(0, 1, 20))
for torque in sin:
    s.set_torque(torque)
    sol = solve_ivp(s.phi_derivatives, t_span=(start_t, end_t), y0=[phi_0, phi_dot_0])
    phi, phi_dot = sol.y
    _, phi_ddot = s.phi_derivatives(0, [phi, phi_dot])
    phi_arr.append(phi)
    phi_dot_arr.append(phi_dot)
    phi_ddot_arr.append(phi_ddot)

    phi_0 = phi[-1]
    phi_dot_0 = phi_dot[-1]
    start_t = end_t
    end_t += 0.05

phi_arr = np.concatenate(phi_arr)
phi_dot_arr = np.concatenate(phi_dot_arr)
phi_ddot_arr = np.concatenate(phi_ddot_arr)
```

notice that for every window I use a torque value that is provided from a sine wave.

Intuitively, I was expecting that the solution `phi` would oscillate to account for the changing direction of the torque, but what I get is this figure (plotting `phi_arr,phi_dot_arr,phi_ddot_arr`):

[image: phi, phi' and phi'' plots]

Do you think that this is a matter of bad implementation? also notice the high values of `phi'` and `phi''`, which are of order `1e12` and `1e26` respectively

Comment: You need to take the version of physics where the friction force is always a friction, removing energy from the system. Meaning its direction has to be opposite to the velocity direction. So replace `- b * (phi_dot ** 2)` with `- b * phi_dot * abs(phi_dot)`.

Comment: Thanks, @LutzLehmann, so essentially you're saying that using phi_dot * abs(phi_dot) is like making sure that the friction force is in the opposite direction w.r.t phi_dot, where on the other hand phi_dot^2 doesn't take that into consideration?

Comment: Yes. In general the friction force for movement in gas-like media is `-c*v*norm(v)`, where `v` is the velocity vector.

Comment: In the current form, as soon as the velocity turns negative, you get quadratic feedback in the same direction, which leads to a pole in the solution, a blow-up to negative infinity in finite time. Especially if `torque` is also negative. You should see this divergence more in context if you put sensible `ylim`s on the last two plots.

Comment: Indeed this has solved my problem. Thanks as always @LutzLehmann

Comment: Would kindly like to ask another question - it seems that in some cases the solution stalls and the velocity tends to zero without actually accounting for the actual torque - for example - using torques from [1,-1,1] in a loop is ok, but [1,-1,1,-1] works up until the last -1, where then the velocity is zero and the solver thinks there are multiple zero crossings. any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I do not see what else you changed, in which way you loop these arrays,... Are the timing parameters used in the question still relevant, or at least which ones are? You have a `delta_t` left that is no longer used,... The model is also not very physical, with jumps in velocity, sharp pulses in the acceleration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247939/discussion-between-hadar-and-lutz-lehmann).